# Is there an injection attack with a user supplied subquery for a where in clause?

Tags: database, sql-injection

We have a feature that allows users to filter a list with a sql statement.

The user supplied statement is in essence used like:

```
select * from table where id in (subquery) -- where subquery is given by the user
```

I tried giving it `); delete from table; --` and `delete from table returning id` but to no avail.
Any other possibilities? I am not worried about the user seeing data, that they can not access otherwise.

Comment: `1); delete from table; --`

Comment: Yes, if the raw subquery is interpolated with the SQL string its vulnerable to injection.  Correctly sanitize the user input and it wont be a problem.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you, that "worked".

Comment: One of my programs has a similar setup (the users are supposed to pass a complete `where` clause and I have to trust it). In my setup, I have a loginness user that owns the objects being referenced (so that no one can login as that user), and another user under which all such queries are executed (which has only one permission: read the data from that one table). Under this setup I don't have to worry if the `where` is valid. If it's not valid in any sense, there will be one exception or another; it will only execute if it's a proper `where` against that single table.

Comment: That still leaves the possibility of a DoS attack if the user comes up with a nice cartesian join `where`, but there are other tools to handle that (e.g. the resource governor in SQL Server).

Answer (score -2):

Your questions are mutually exclusive, due to the fact that you are confusing an *injection* with a particular *exploit*.

> Is there an injection attack with a user supplied subquery for a where in clause?

Yes, of course. The ability to inject an arbitrary SQL code is exactly what an SQL injection is.

> I tried giving it ); delete from table; -- and delete from table returning id but to no avail.

In most circumstances this particular query won't work.

> Any other possibilities?

Yes, of course. Mostly regarding the user seeing the data, that they can not access otherwise.

> I am not worried about the user seeing data

So make your mind: whether you do care for SQL injections at whole or for the particular subset only.

Comment: They can usually see the entire table. The subquery is there to let them filter the rows.

Comment: It's not about seeing the only table, but having the read  access to the entire database.

Comment: How would that work in a subquery? The only part that is user supplied, is the subquery part. I don't think it can leak data then.

Comment: @ThijsWouters so thought thousands of webmasters, only to find that info was leaked